# Aggregate table with dates and average geographic coordinates

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, r, coordinates

When `SOG` is 0 `Stops` gets 1. When the next `SOG` is 0 then `Stops` gets 2 and like this consecutively.

Now I want to group all the rows where `SOG != 0`. The trick is that I should have the following fields:

`MinTime`: minimum value of `BS` and `TS`, ie., date and time of boat arrival to port.

`MaxTime`: maximum value of `BS` and `TS`

`Duration`: difference between `MinTime` and `MaxTime`

`AveLat` and `AveLong`: Average Latitude and Longitude. Probably the most challenging. See formula at the bottom of the message.

This is what I have:

```
      MMSI       BS       TS      LAT     LONG SOG SIZE_A Stops
 247117300 6.4.2014 15:56:07 57.71432 11.96005   0     46     1
 247117300 6.4.2014 16:05:07 57.71433 11.96005   0     46     1
 247117300 6.4.2014 16:11:07 57.71432 11.96005   0     46     1
 247117300 6.4.2014 16:20:06 57.71433 11.96005   0     46     1
 247117300 6.4.2014 16:29:06 57.71433 11.96003   0     46     1
 247117300 6.4.2014 16:29:27 57.71433 11.96003   4     46     0
 247117300 6.4.2014 16:34:28 57.71433 11.96003   4     46     0
 247117300 6.4.2014 16:37:29 57.71433 11.96003   4     46     0
 247117300 6.4.2014 17:14:40 57.71433 11.96003   4     46     0
 247117300 6.4.2014 17:18:30 57.71432 11.96003   4     46     0
 247117300 6.4.2014 17:22:50 57.71433 11.96002   4     46     0
 247117300 6.4.2014 17:27:01 57.71432 11.96002   4     46     0
 247117300 6.4.2014 17:29:09 57.71435 11.96003   0     46     2
 247117300 6.4.2014 17:33:50 57.71435 11.96003   0     46     2
 247117300 6.4.2014 17:39:49 57.71437 11.96003   0     46     2
 247117300 6.4.2014 17:42:51 57.71435 11.96003   0     46     2
 247117300 6.4.2014 17:51:49 57.71433 11.96003   0     46     2
 247117300 6.4.2014 17:52:37 57.71432 11.96002   0     46     2
 247117300 6.4.2014 17:58:26 57.71212 11.95697   3     46     0
 247117300 6.4.2014 18:00:26 57.71047 11.95567   4     46     0
```

This is the desired result  (AveLAT and AveLONG are fake):

```
     MMSI       BS       TS      LAT     LONG SOG SIZE_A Stops           MinTime           MaxTime Duration_min   AveLAT   AveLON
247117300 6.4.2014 15:56:07 57.71432 11.96005   0     46     1 6.4.2014 15:56:07 6.4.2014 16:29:06           34 57.71432 11.96005
247117300 6.4.2014 17:29:09 57.71435 11.96003   0     46     2 6.4.2014 17:29:09 6.4.2014 17:52:37           23 57.71433 11.96003
```

I have done the previous operations in R but I could also use ArcMap or whatever program solves it.

Formula to get Average LAT and LONG (from [this website](http://www.geomidpoint.com/calculation.html))

1. LatToRadians: value*Pi/180
2. LongToRadians: value*Pi/180
3. X_cartesian: COS(LatToRadians) * COS(LongToRadians)
4. Y_Cartesian: COS(LatToRadians) * SIN(LongToRadians)
5. Z_Cartesian: SIN(LatToRadians)
6. AveX: SUM (X_Cartesian)/ all occurrences of X_Cartesian
7. AveY: SUM (Y_Cartesian)/ all occurrences of Y_Cartesian
8. AveZ: SUM (Z_Cartesian)/ all occurrences of Z_Cartesian
9. LAT: Inverse tangent (HYP, AveZ)
10. LONG: Inverse tangent (AveX, AveY)
11. HYP: Square root(AveX * AveX + AveY * AveY)
    12: LATMean: LAT * 180 / PI
12. LONGMean: LONG * 180 / PI

Comment: The base function to apply a function to a conditional factor is ?tapply

Answer (score 1):

First, you should add some fields :

1) sogtest (select by attribute SOG!=0, and use field calculator to fill the selected values with 1)

2) X, Y and Z (use the field calculator to compute your "cartesian" coordinates)

Then you can use "dissolve"(or summarize table if you don"t need to merge the geometries) with sogtest as a case field and the required statistics of the other fields.

3) finally, you use the field calculator again to revert to Lat and Long coordinates

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Someone posted an example in Stackoverflow to do it with R. I will try with that first